# AOS installation error in Dynamics AX

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

i am trying to install tha Dynamics AX in windows server 2012. i have created the databases using Database installation in AX Dynamics setup in SQL Server. Now i am trying to install the AOS feature but i am getting the like this[image: AOS installation]

[image: connected to database]

[image: error details]
the error is "Setup cannot use the database MicrosoftDynamicsAx in server VENKAT because its Collation is incorrect". please help me with this error.

Comment: Please check the following link http://sinedax.blogspot.com.by/2012/11/ax-2012-sql-server-collation.html

Comment: What is the collation of the AX databases?

Comment: He answered the question about the current collation in [a thread about the same question in Dynamics Community](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/240082).

Comment: this is not a programming question

Comment: this is not a programming question @AnthonyBlake but the problem is related to Dynamics AX only.

Comment: @venkatpasumarthi problem here is stackoverflow is for programming questions, i think you may get a better answer elsewhere

Answer (score 3):

the collation error is rectified I have changed the collation to 
`SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI` to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` in the database. the query is 
`ALTER DATABASE MicrosoftDynamicsAX1 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;`

Comment: I am having the same issue. You created a new database ? in your query above I see MicrosoftDynamicsAX1 instead of MicrosoftDynamicsAX as you stated in your question from the first place. Can you clearly explain the steps so other people can get a cleaner solution with this issue ? Thanks!

Comment: First of all, you can use the same database. I have deleted the first database MicrosoftDynamicsAX because I don't know the fix at the time and then recreated the date base MicrosoftDynamicsAX1. But the problem still exists, so I have used the above query to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute the follow queries:

```
ALTER DATABASE MicrosoftDynamicsAX COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI;
```

GO

```
ALTER DATABASE MicrosoftDynamicsAX COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
```